# Which algorithm to use for sorting a sequence of strings into blocks avoiding beginnig with a certain element?

Tags: string, algorithm, sorting, sequence

Let's say there is a list: `['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b']`.

Which algorithm can you use to sort it into groups which have 2-4 elements?
There should be as little as possible groups beginning with `'b'`.

In this example: `aa | aba | abbb`

This is for a homework to find a optimal algorithm.

Comment: What is not working with your attempt?

Answer (score 1):

If we are allowed to change the order of the elements, the problem is trivial: just group all the `a`s and insert three `b`s after every `a` while possible, creating groups of size 4 (or less if there aren't enough `b`s). After that, if there are any remaining `b`s, group them in groups of size 4; otherwise, group the remaining `a`s as you like.

If we are obliged to keep the element order, the problem becomes more interesting and we can solve it in `O(n)` where `n` is the number of elements using the following recurrence: let `f(i, j)` represent the number of groups starting with `b` in an optimal collection up to index `i`, where this element is the `j`th one of its group. (Since `j` ranges from 2 to 4, the complexity is `O(3n) = O(n)`.) Then:

```
f(i, j) =
  if A[i - j + 1] == 'b':
    return 1 + min(f(i - j, k)), for 1 < k < 5
  else:
    return min(f(i - j, k)), for 1 < k < 5
```

Naive top-down in JavaScript:

```js
function f(A, i, j){
  if (j > i + 1 || i == 0)
    return Infinity
  if (i == 1)
    return A[0] == 'b' ? 1 : 0

  let prev = Infinity
  
  for (let k=2; k<5; k++)
    prev = Math.min(f(A, i - j, k), prev)
    
  return prev + (A[i - j + 1] == 'b' ? 1 : 0)
}

var A = "aaabaabbb"
console.log(A)
for (let j=2; j<5; j++)
  console.log(`If the last char is ${j + [,,'nd','rd','th'][j]}, then optimal is ${f(A, A.length-1, j)}`)

A = "aaabaabbbb"
console.log('\n' + A)
for (let j=2; j<5; j++)
  console.log(`If the last char is ${j + [,,'nd','rd','th'][j]}, then optimal is ${f(A, A.length-1, j)}`)
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? i and j do not uniquely identify a set of partitions. Also what is the output suppose to represent? Is 1 non-optimal and 0 is optimal?

Comment: @AlexMayle sorry it wasn't clear. OP requested "as little as possible groups beginning with 'b'." `f(i, j)` is supposed to return the number of groups starting with `b` in an optimal solution (see amended description). We should be able to get the actual partition as well by augmenting the code slightly.